Override parameterNames in EntityPersister to include composite key attribute
There is a column CreatedDate which is updated to be part of composite key in postgresql. @IdClass is used to define the composite key. After the change of adding it as part of composite key, CreatedDate is not added as a propertyName in the org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister of that class which is leading to this error.
Property createdDate not found

Is there a way we can update the propertyNames of an EntityPersister so that it includes the key attributes as well?
